# I can't debug an application using netbeans 11 with JavaFX 12

Tags: javafx, netbeans, javafx-11, openjfx

I've downloaded netbeans 11 with support for java 12
So I followed up the steps from the Gluon webpage running JavaFX and Netbeans Non modular with maven >  https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#next-steps

I have configured as showed in the instructions the action to run this app.

Run Project
clean javafx:run

But there is nothing specified to debug the project.
Is there a way to debug this javaFX project?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimonSaysGFX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.simonsaysgfx.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>SimonSaysGFX</name>
</project>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you see the [documentation](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) of the `javafx-maven-plugin`, you can add some VM arguments to the `run` goal  in order to debug your project in NetBeans.

However, to keep the usual `run` goal ready to just run the project and not debug, without commenting out the added options, we can add a second execution to the plugin.

Modify your plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.simonsaysgfx.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <!-- Configuration for debugging -->
            <id>debug</id>
            <configuration>
                <options>
                    <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:8000</option>
                </options>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.simonsaysgfx.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now you can run from command line:

```
mvn clean javafx:run
```

to run as usual your application, and:

```
mvn clean javafx:run@debug
```

to start debug mode. Then you will see something like:

```
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.2:run (debug) @ Project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /path/to/project/target/classes
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

At this point, you need to set your breakpoints and attach a debugger from `NetBeans -> Debug -> Attach Debugger` to port 8000:

[image: debugger]

Click OK and you will be able to debug your projects.

Note that you can also define custom NetBeans actions to use the Run and Debug buttons. Add a `nbactions.xml` file to the root of your project, with this two actions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>javafx:run</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>jlink</actionName>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>javafx:jlink</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
    <action>
        <actionName>debug</actionName>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>javafx:run@debug</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Now you can use NetBeans run and debug buttons.

Answer (score 15):

José's answer is good. Just go little bit further.

In `pom.xml` set the 
`address=${jpda.address}` instead of `address=*:8000`

```
    <execution>
        <!-- Configuration for debugging -->
        <id>debug</id>
        <configuration>
            <options>
                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
            </options>
            <mainClass>cz.masci.mvcpattern.mvc.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Be aware of set server=n, otherwise the application will not start.

In the debug action set `jpda.listen=true` property

```
   ...
    <action>
        <actionName>debug</actionName>
        <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>javafx:run@debug</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
        </properties>
    </action>
```

Then you don't need to attach debuger anymore. Netbeans does it for you.

Comment: Does not work using Apache NetBeans 12 + javafx maven plugin 0.0.4

Comment: @Birdasaur Works for me with NetBeans 12.3 and javafx-maven-plugin 0.0.4