# OpenJFX Custom runtime image using Maven and jlink - Module exports or command line arguments?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11, openjfx

I'm trying to create a custom runtime image that will not require installed JRE/JDK on the computer. I have followed the tutorial presented on OpenJFX Documentation (JavaFX and IntelliJ - Modular with Maven) and I am able to run the created image, but I want to include for my application class com.sun.glass.ui.Window (in module javafx.graphics).

Before custom images, I was parsing as command line arguments the following:
--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED

I want to include this in runtime, so should I modify the pom from Maven to include for javafx-maven-plugin a  (not successful) or should I edit the project module.info to export the requested package from javafx.graphics.

Thanks,
Andrei

Pom.xml
module.info.java

```
module com.andrei {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    exports com.andrei;
    exports com.sun.glass.ui to com.andrei;
}
```

"Package "com.sun.glass.ui" is declared in module "javafx.graphics", which does not export to module "com.andrei" "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javafx-maven-plugin` should be able to do what you are trying to do. However, it doesn't do it so far, so I've just filed these two issues: [Options for javafx:run are incompatible with javafx:jlink](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/22) and [Missing link vm options parameter](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/23).

While this gets resolved and a new version is published, there is an easy (but manual) fix:

**Compilation time**

Before modifying the `javafx-maven-plugin`, you need to allow your IDE to work with the private package. You can't do it from the module-info, but you can easily do that from the `maven-compiler-plugin` using `compilerArgs`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports</arg>
            <arg>javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=com.andrei</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now in your code you can make use of that private package, and IntelliJ won't complain.

After running from the Maven window `Lifecycle -> clean`, and `Lifecycle -> compile`, something like this is allowed in the editor:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    ...
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Runtime**

However, if you do `mvn clean compile javafx:run`, the code above will fail:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.andrei.Main (in module com.andrei) cannot access class com.sun.glass.ui.Window (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.ui to module com.andrei.

As explained in the plugin [readme](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxrun-options), you cad add VM options that will be passed to the `java` tool:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <options>
            <option>--add-opens</option>
            <option>javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=com.andrei</option>
        </options>
        ...
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now you can run: `mvn clean compile javafx:run`, and that will work, and you will get information for the current stage printed out.

**Runtime image**

Finally, if you run: `mvn clean compile javafx:jlink`, this will fail, because the content in `<options>` is not recognized by `jlink` (first issue filed), so you have to comment it out:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--<options>-->
          <!--<option>--add-opens</option>-->
          <!--<option>javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=com.andrei</option>-->
        <!--</options>-->
        <launcher>launcher</launcher>
        <mainClass>com.andrei/com.andrei.Main</mainClass>
    ...
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now `mvn clean compile javafx:jlink` will work, but when running you will get the same error as above because the private package is not exported.

However, you can edit the launcher file under `target/image/bin/launcher`:

```
#!/bin/sh
JLINK_VM_OPTIONS=
DIR=`dirname $0`
$DIR/java $JLINK_VM_OPTIONS -m com.andrei/com.andrei.Main $@
```

As you can see, there is an empty `JLINK_VM_OPTIONS` variable that can be filled with your vm options.

Until the second issue filed is solved, just modify that line:

```
#!/bin/sh
JLINK_VM_OPTIONS="--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=com.andrei"
DIR=`dirname $0`
$DIR/java $JLINK_VM_OPTIONS -m fx/org.openjfx.MainApp $@
```

save, and run: `target/image/bin/launcher`, and it will work.

Comment: I will follow the status of your requests on GitHub for further updates regarding this topics. Thank you again!

Comment: @AndreiD I've just filed a PR that should fix both issues. If you want to test it in advance, clone and install the plugin from [here](https://github.com/jperedadnr/javafx-maven-plugin) with `mvn clean install`, and then use in your project with version `0.0.3-SNAPSHOT`. Your feedback is welcome.

Comment: I have tried to clone, but I get:  The POM for org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available.

Comment: also I have one more question. Is it possible to  to attach a remote debugger? using -agentlib

Comment: For debugging see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56207033/3956070).

Comment: After cloning from github the project. should I insert in pom.xml file the following: <properties>...  <sdk>C:\Users\andrei\Documents\javafx-maven-plugin-master</sdk> ... </properties> ?

Comment: <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                        <arg>javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=com.andrei</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: <configuration>
                        <source>12</source>
                        <target>12</target>
                        <release>12</release>
                        <options>
                            <option>--add-opens</option>
                            <option>javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=com.andrei</option>
                        </options>
                        <mainClass>com.andrei.App</mainClass>
                    </configuration>

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.2:jlink (default-cli) on project javafx-maven-setup: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Clone the plugin, set JDK 11, and run `mvn clean install`, then you can use `0.0.3-SNAPSHOT` in plugin's version of your end project's pom. That's it.