# How to export a javafx maven project with jfoenix components using the javafx-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jfoenix

I have been working on a javaFx project with maven. exporting this project to an executable file seems to very hard.

though my research i found that javafx-maven-plugin is the tool for that and with the help of my last question i figured out the configuration to run the project using the plugin.

[How to run a maven java fx project that includes jfoenix using javafx-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471051/how-to-run-a-maven-java-fx-project-that-includes-jfoenix-using-javafx-maven-plug/61473762?noredirect=1#comment108779433_61473762)

my assumption was that if i could get the project to run, then exporting using the same tool can be easy. but i have been try all possible changes and nothing works.

export the project using

```
mvn javafx:jlink
```

run the project by using the following cmd at the bin

```
java -m "moduleName"/"reference of the the main class"
```

all the technical information are in the linked question. how can i export this project properly.