# How to debug JavaFX application with jdk14/javafx14/Eclipse v.2020-03?

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, openjfx

I'm trying to run a JavaFX application to test some custom controls based on jdk14 and JavaFX14. My operating system is Windows 10, the IDE is Eclipse 2020-03, and I use m2e Maven plugin. The controls are exact copies of controls developed under jdk8 and JavaFX8; the earlier controls pass all tests, there was no problem with debugging.

There is no problem getting a test application to *run* using jdk14 and JavaFX14, but breakpoints are ignored regardless of whether I run in debug mode, or run mode, or whether I modify the Maven command from javafx:run to javafx:debug (that did NOT work) or to javafx:run@debug.

This issue seems to have been addressed several times in the context of a Netbeans IDE (see [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197372/i-cant-debug-an-application-using-netbeans-11-with-javafx-12/56207033#56207033), and I copied in the text from the modified plugin as suggested, but to no effect.

I have the following questions:

1. What must be done in order to debug a JavaFX application under the conditions described above?
2. Who is responsible for dealing with this? Eclipse? OpenJFX? Somebody else?
3. Based on the principle that whatever solution is developed, it should be as user friendly as the debugging process under jdk8 and JavaFX8 (i.e. before JavaFX and everything else got decoupled from Oracle), is it reasonable to expect that a solution along those lines will be available in the near future? Is anybody working on it now?

Thanks for feedback.

Comment: I prefer to launch Maven in "debug mode" with `mvnDebug ...` and then attach a remote debugger from whatever IDE I'm using. Eclipse may offer an easier way with some sort of "Debug as..." configuration; my experience with something similar in IntelliJ is that ends up debugging _Maven_ (or Gradle) and not the process forked by Maven (or Gradle), hence my preference for attaching a remote debugger. But I'm not familiar with Eclipse so it may handle such things better.

Comment: Using `javafx:run@debug` should work, however, provided you added the execution in the pom file, as shown in the answer to the linked question.