# How to debug a Maven OpenJFX application in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, openjfx

Since JavaFX has become OpenJFX and needs to be added as a dependency to your Maven project, debugging a OpenJFX application has become complicated. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197372/i-cant-debug-an-application-using-netbeans-11-with-javafx-12) it is already answered how to solve it for NetBeans. But IntelliJ works slightly different. The Ppom.xml has been setup according to [this example](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/Maven/hellofx/pom.xml).

How can you run an OpenJFX (JavaFX) application which is configured as a Maven project in debug mode in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would copy the addition of VM options in the pom.xml for javafx-maven-plugin as given by [José Pereda here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197372/i-cant-debug-an-application-using-netbeans-11-with-javafx-12), you can run the application with 'mvn javafx:run@debug' and then manually attach it to the IntelliJ Debugger by go to the menu 'Run - Attach to process...' and the select your application.

However, if you want debugger and application to be started with a single click, IntelliJ is a but troublesome. You can create a Remote Debug configuration which first launches your application and the debugger serially. Or have Compound Configurations which does both in parallel. The problem is to get them synchronized.

I found the following solution. Make your application run as debug client and the IntelliJ debugger as server. The VM options for the javafx-maven-plugin in the pom.xml file should have 'server=n':

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.waninge.test.JFXTest</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Configuration for debugging -->
                    <id>debug</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <options>
                            <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=localhost:8000,suspend=y</option>
                        </options>
                        <mainClass>org.waninge.test.JFXTest</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Create a Maven Run Configuration in IntelliJ with 'javafx:run@debug' in the 'Command line'.
Create a Remote Run Configuration with the following settings:

- Debugger mode: 'Listen to remote JVM';
- Transport: 'Socket';
- Host: as in the pom
- Port: as in the pom

Now the Remote Run Configuration will start a debug server waiting for clients. The Maven Run Configuration will connect to the debug server, or fail if the debug server isn't online.

Now, to get everything started with a single click, you can create a Compound Run Configuration and add the Maven and the Remote Run Configuration to it. Starting this configuration will launch the two in parallel, and you can debug your application.